# from set of tuples of coordinates back to a variable assignment in Python

Tags: python, tuples, coordinates, variable-assignment

I have a tuple of tuple coordinates I'd like to change to their assigned variable. Below is just a sample of 4 tuples containing a tuple of 4 coordinates. I actually have over 100.

```
all_4s = ((1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (-1, 3)), ((-1, 4), (0, 3), (0, 2), (1, 3)), /
         ((-1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2))

# I want to change the tuple 'all_4s' into their variable name assignments, i.e.
A1 = (1, 1)
A2 = (1, 2)
A3 = (1, 3)
A4 = (1, 4)
B1 = (0, 1)
B2 = (0, 2)
B3 = (0, 3)
B4 = (0, 4)
C1 = (-1, 1)
C2 = (-1, 2)
C3 = (-1, 3)
C4 = (-1, 4)

# back to how they originally were:
all_4s = ((A2, B2, B3, C3), (C3, B3, B2, A3)) # ... + ~100 more
```

It's easier to read this way instead of having to look at coordinates. I have about half of my `all_4s` tuple still in coordinates form. Basically I am referencing these coordinates to check if any are a subset of a larger tuple of coordinates, i.e. ((A1, A2, B1, C1, B2, C2, C3, B4)). So I have been changing them to sets to do this. My program works fine in referencing the tuples. The kindly-provided solutions below show how to change them to string form, i.e. ('A1, 'B2', 'C3', 'A3), but in doing so, I'm afraid they will lose their coordinates reference.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dictionary is better than storing in different variables.
Add all the variables here, I've only added a few to check

```
all_4s = ((1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (-1, 3)), ((-1, 4), (0, 3), (0, 2), (1, 3)), /
             ((-1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2))

var = {
    'A2' : (1, 2),
    'B2' : (0, 2),
    'C3' : (0, 3),
    'C4' : (-1, 3)
}

new_tuple = tuple(list(var.keys())[list(var.values()).index(i)] for i in all_4s)
```

I've used this approach but it is a bit complicated to understand. Basically for every value in all_4s, we find the corresponding key in the dictionary and then form the new tuple.

Comment: I tried your approach however I got this error:
`code`    new_tuple = tuple(list(var.keys())[list(var.values()).index(i)] for i in all_4s)
ValueError: ((1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (-1, 3)) is not in list `code`

Comment: Yes, so like I've mentioned in my answer, I've not taken all the possible variables in var. For eg: (-1,4) is in all_4s but not in the dictionary, so first add all the variables in var and then try

Comment: I've added all 12 variables to var like so:
var = {
    'A1': (1, 1), 'A2': (1, 2), 'A3': (1, 3), 'A4': (1, 4), 'B1': (0, 1), 'B2': (0, 2), 'B3': (0, 3), 
    'B4': (0, 4),  'C1': (-1, 1), 'C2': (-1, 2), 'C3': (-1, 3), 'C4': (-1, 4),
    }

However same error. It works if there's only  one tuple set. Also, I need to have the new_tuple be indicated like this: new_tuple = ((A2, B2, B3, C3), (C3, B3, B2, A3))... and not with strings 'A1', 'B2', ...etc.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of iterating on the names and comparing with each element in the tuple is very close to Prats's one. But I tried to be more understandable for beginners and not to be complicated. Notice that tuples are immutable. So you can not change it and I had to convert them to list and convert them back.

```
all_4s = ((1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (-1, 3)), ((-1, 4), (0, 3), (0, 2), (1, 3)), ((-1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2))
names = {
    'A2': (1, 2),
    'B2': (0, 2),
    'C3': (0, 3),
    'C4': (-1, 4)
    }
all_4s = list(all_4s)

for eachIndex in range(len(all_4s)):
    all_4s[eachIndex] = list(all_4s[eachIndex])
    for eachCoordinateIndex in range(len(all_4s[eachIndex])):
        for eachName in names:
            if all_4s[eachIndex][eachCoordinateIndex] == names[eachName]:
                all_4s[eachIndex][eachCoordinateIndex] = eachName
    all_4s[eachIndex] = tuple(all_4s[eachIndex])

all_4s = tuple(all_4s)
print(all_4s)
```

Output:

```
(('A2', 'B2', 'C3', (-1, 3)), ('C4', 'C3', 'B2', (1, 3)), ((-1, 1), (0, 1), 'B2', 'A2'))
```

Comment: This is good, though I just need for the tuples not be strings, simply ((A2, B2, C3, ...)) As I need to reference my entire tuple in my program and check for each case (each tuple set) if they exist.

Comment: @cpsharp Think about the types. A2 for example need to have a type and can't be other than string. Also, I suggest you vote for any answer that can be useful. :)

Comment: Hmm, so for what I'm doing may not work with a dictionary maybe. In my program, I need to be able to look into my tuple `all_4s` to check if any tuple is a subset of either 3 coordinates or a subset of 4 coordinates. That's for the replies.

Comment: @cpsharp It's not a matter of the solution. You never can have a tuple like this ((A2, B2, C3, ...)) instead of (('A2', 'B2', 'C3', ...)).